# Pygithub - Organization Repo - Access Pull Requests Details

Tags: python, pygithub

I am using Pygithub for a public repo , I am new to it, how do I access my organization repo(private) Pull Request details , given that , from my settings i had generated OAuth Tokens and Private Tokens.

Answer (score 3):

You need to authenticate with your token first:

```
from github import Github
git = Github('TOKEN')
```

Then you need to get the repo from your organisation:

```
repo = git.get_organization(org_name).get_repo(repo_name)
```

And finally, you can get the pull request by number:

```
pull = repo.get_pull(pull_request_number)
```